# How can my python program do work and serve results via FastAPI at the same time?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn, asgi

I have a Python program that reads financial market data to do some analysis. I want to offer the results of the analysis via FastAPI. The problem is that when I start the uvicorn server for fastAPI, the rest of my Python program, especially the main loop, is nnot executed properly.

It is unclear to me how I can use FastAPI in a Python program that also has to do other work. This is what my main.py looks like (left out imports for simplicity...):

```
# Add fastAPI.
app = FastAPI()

# Start market scanner.
ms1 = MarketScanner(name="ms1", sample_size=10)

# Get the root.
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Welcome": "to analyst."}

# For test purpose, get length of the current market data cache.
@app.get("/mdata/")
def read_market_data_len():
    mdata = ms1.get_market_data_len()
    #print(f"mdata: {mdata}")
    return {"Market data length": mdata}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ms1.start()
    while True:
        ms1.get_new_market_data()
        print(f"market data length: {ms1.get_market_data_len()}")
        time.sleep(3)
```

I start the uvicorn server from a command line:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

When the unicorn server is running, I start the Python program with

```
python main.py
```

I can see the market data length from the print in the while-loop increase, so my `MarketScanner` is fetching data from the financial data provider, but when I navigate to 127.0.0.1:8000/mdata in my browser, I always see "Market data length: 0", it just never increases.

I am a bit lost here, how can I built a python app with a fastAPI, but also a lot of other features that it handles in the background?

Comment: I'd recommend to check out celery or other similar background schedulers. It's possible with raw Python, of course (just run a separate script and share results via database or plain files), but celery can provide better control.

Comment: You mean this one: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/index.html ?

Comment: Yes, especially [this part](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: Anything your marketscanner fetches will only live _inside that single process_. Since you're running that in a process by itself, there is nothing that gets coordinated to the `uvicorn` process you're running - these two live completely by themselves. You'll need to explicitly exchange information in some way, for example through a database/sqlite file (i.e. one process updates the database, another one reads the most recent data). This will probably be good enough for your use case, but there's other ways like shared memory etc. - but then you're exchanging  maintainability for performance.

Comment: Also check out [FastAPI background tasks capabilities](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/)

Comment: How long should we expect `ms1.get_new_market_data()` to take? How exactly does `ms1.get_market_data_len()` interact with that? For example, does it have to do any significant calculation? What should happen if there is a web request that wants to compute and return `ms1.get_market_data_len()`, but `ms1.get_new_market_data()` is in the middle of running?

Comment: ms1.get_new_market_data() should take 10 seconds and stores the result in a list which is an attribute of MarketScanner. ms1.get_market_data_len() is a getter and returns that list from the ms1 object. If there is a webrequest triggering ms1.get_market_data_len() it would just get the current value of ms1's attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you are running two different processes, one serving the web app and the other running this module alone.  Those two programs are completely separate from one-another.  Each process has its own MarketScanner instance that is completely independent of the other.

One option is to move your MarketScanner into a function and run that function in a thread at module import time.

Comment: In this simplified example i only have the MarketScanner, but the whole application has more action going on, currently in different threads. Threadpool executors and async operations, so i assume its better to leave the control over that to the main loop. But thanks for hinting on the two separate instances, that makes sense of course! I guess i have to implement some interprocess communication between the business logic and the fastAPI then.

Comment: Correct, if you want two processes, they will need some form of IPC (interprocess communication).  A common way of doing that is via a shared state mechanism like Redis or a relational database (e.g., PostgreSQL).

Comment: Ok, not hundred percent familiar with the whole backend orchestration, but is it like you said more common to just use a DB as a shared storage or a task delivery system like celery worker docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/index.html